# Show that an operation of elements in a finite group contains each elements exactly once

Tags: abstract-algebra

Finite group $G$ contains elements $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$. Show $g_1g,g_2g,...,g_ng$ contains each element of G exactly once.

I know that by definition $g_ig$ is an element of group $G$. How can I prove by contradiction that $g_ig$ does not equal $g_jg$?

Comment: If $g_{i}g = g_{j}g$, what do you get by multiplying by $g^{-1}$?

Comment: @Lucas Corrêa thanks

Comment: Not again! This is the same question the 3rd time! See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958332/abstract-algebra-show-that-if-the-finite-group-g-comprises-the-elements).

Answer (score -1):

$g_igg^-1 = g_jgg^-1$
$g_i = g_j$
Since we know $g_i$ does not in fact equal $g_j$ we have proved by contradiction.